# php tags are ignored and parsed as comments

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have a very strange problem.
I installed a new XAMPP distribution yesterday and it behaves very strangely.

I have two files, page.php and include.php.

"page.php" has the following code:

```
<? include('include.php'); ?>
```

The file "include.php" has the following line:

```
<? echo "it works"; ?>
```

Now: If I open start.php in my web browser, it shows me an empty page, and the source code reads:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!--? echo "it works"; -->
</body>
</html>
```

As you see, the php code on the start.php is interpreted correctly, but the php-code on include.php is parsed as a comment?!?!

I have a XAMPP server on Mac OS 10.9.4. And OF COURSE I have

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Thanks for your help!
Matt

Comment: Does it work with `<?php`? I'd generally not use the short tag because of compatibility issues.

Comment: make sure to restart the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downdgraded back to XAMPP 1.7.3, no problems so far, php tags are treated normally again...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<?php` tags , because your php.ini settings might restrict you

Comment: He said, he changed the value of `short_open_tag`, so thats not the problem i guess.

Comment: yup its easy enough to change but he might not have restated his apache or edited the wrong .ini file

Comment: OP seems competent enough for that, judging by his knowledge about the settings. Even if he just read it somewhere, it should work properly.

Comment: I have restarted the server, and edited the correct php.ini, that's why I was sure it has nothing to do with <php short tags in the first place. but thanks for your replies.

Comment: what editor are you using ? can you try and edit with something basic to make sure it is actually having the write html code / php code

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a parser error for the shortcode in XAMPP. Try the full
`<?PHP ... ?>`. Also how do you access the file path? Make sure to use https://localhost:8080/start.php and not a local file path - obviously change the port to your own.

Let me know if this doesn't work as I have tested and its fine on my Mac following this method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can just use `<?php ?>` just like that, if you really want to use the short_open_tag try to reinstall the XAMPP, activate the module, then restart all the services.